# Jmeter Http proxy server throws java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index error

Tags: java, jmeter, urlencode, put

I am trying to record my web client-server communication using Jmeter. After the Jmeter and browser are configured for recording the application. When a post request is made from client to server, the following error happens. Any idea how to encode the URL which is being recorded?

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 238: http://localhost:8080/updateBoxCorrectionInstantly?examKey=16-17-%3ECBSE-%3ETERM%20I-%3ESA1-%3EVI-%3EScience-%3EA&studentName=AMOGH%20YOGESH%20KALE&studentRollno=3&studentND=-1&sheetName=cb8e806b32e9d670698655e0d2da10e3_img001210.jpg&box={%22$center%22:%22(66.0,%202253.0)%22,%22$conf%22:%22H%22,%22$corrected%22:true,%22$isAdminCorrected%22:true,%22$correction%22:%22-%22,%22$isDrawn%22:false,%22coords%22:[36,2214,96,2292],%22isTitle%22:false,%22pos%22:%22-%22,%22pred%22:%22-%22,%22boxTypeId%22:0,%22score%22:1}
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3092)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3034)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
at java.net.URL.toURI(URL.java:949)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:232)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1075)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:212)
```

Comment: This might help you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79057/curly-brackets-in-urls

Comment: this happened during recording or replaying? did you try using `http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode` function?

Comment: is your request actually 'POST' ? why are you sending so many url parameters for post request? Could you not send them as part of request body using formurlencoded request property?

Answer (score 2):

Specifically that exception is about curly braces in your URI:

```
/updateBoxCorrectionInstantly?<...>_img001210.jpg&box={
```

Curly brackets are considered [unsafe](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html):

> Other characters are unsafe because gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~", "[", "]", and "`". All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL.

So you could replace all instances of the `{` with `%7B`, and all instances of `}` with `%7D`. My guess is that recorder is not encoding them because curly brackets are not "special" characters (they are just "unsafe"), while URI parser does not like them. So you can consider it a bug in JMeter recorder. Thus minimal solution is to set **Path** to:

```
/updateBoxCorrectionInstantly?examKey=16-17-%3ECBSE-%3ETERM%20I-%3ESA1-%3EVI-%3EScience-%3EA&studentName=AMOGH%20YOGESH%20KALE&studentRollno=3&studentND=-1&sheetName=cb8e806b32e9d670698655e0d2da10e3_img001210.jpg&box=%7B%22$center%22:%22(66.0,%202253.0)%22,%22$conf%22:%22H%22,%22$corrected%22:true,%22$isAdminCorrected%22:true,%22$correction%22:%22-%22,%22$isDrawn%22:false,%22coords%22:[36,2214,96,2292],%22isTitle%22:false,%22pos%22:%22-%22,%22pred%22:%22-%22,%22boxTypeId%22:0,%22score%22:1%7D
```

However, I think a more elegant solution is saving all parameters (past the `?` mark) in **Parameters** section, which has few advantages:

1. It has an option to automatically encode them
2. You can clearly see which parameters you are sending
3. You can use variables when you need to instead of static values (you can in Path as well, but not without a lot of tedious and error-prone configuring)

Here's a screenshot of how I would create this request:

[image]

Because the **Method** is set to `GET`, all parameters are going to be part of URL anyways, but they will be properly encoded, so here's how it's sent:

[image]

Comment: So, the solutions can be any one of the following 
1. Encode the URL in application 
2. Record the request and format the request again before starting the recorded sequence

Answer (score 0):

try using $ before every {}.Thanks

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.